# Find a $3\times 3$ real matrix with no zero entries with the given complex eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

For example, the eigenvalues are: $$x,a+bi,a-bi\ .\ \{a,b,x\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}.$$

I tried solving it directly by solving matrices of the form
$$\
  \begin{vmatrix}
    x & * & * \\
    * & a & -b \\
    * & b & a
  \end{vmatrix}$$

but only got examples with complex numbers in the $*$ fields.

Comment: Is $x$ supposed to be real?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    x & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & a & -b \\
    0 & b & a
  \end{pmatrix}$$
works, but it has zeros, so try instead
$$
U^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
    x & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & a & -b \\
    0 & b & a
  \end{pmatrix}U$$
for some invertible matrix $U$.